# Add mp4 video to jodit rich text editor

Tags: reactjs, frontend, jodit

I want a insert/upload a mp4 file in jodit rich text editor. The video icon seems to allow only url /embedded code option but I don’t find a way which will give either this from locally saved mp4 video .